# Drift Condition Markov Chains Intuition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Given a small set $C \subset X$ with respect to a transition kernel P, that is :

$$P(x,)\ge\lambda \nu()$$

for a probability measure $\nu$ on $X$ and for any $x\in C$ then the same set satisfies  a drift condition
for a function $V:X\rightarrow[1,\infty]$ such that

$$\int_{X}P(x,dy)V(dy)\le \lambda V(x)+b\mathbb{I}_{C}(x)$$ for a $0<\lambda<1$ and $b<\infty$. If this property holds for all $x\in X$ it is stated that the chain returns to C at a fast rate. I am failing to see the intuition why this guarantees my returning to C "fast" enough?